# How to get a count of same values in the same column of two files in linux shell?

Tags: linux, comparison

If you have two files of the same tab separated format, and you want to get a count of how many values in that column are the same between the two files, what would be the best way to do that?

Example:
I have five columns of tab separated data, column two file1 is as follows:

> ```
> 234839
> 349583
> 444995
> 694038
> 785948
> ```

and in file2 column 2 is this:

> ```
> 123943
> 234839
> 338273
> 349583
> 785948
> ```

The expected output would be 3.

Comment: Example input and output please.

Comment: Added example input/output.
Edit: John you're too quick for me.

Comment: Well you added example input but not output.

Comment: You're too quick for me. It's all in now.

Comment: You say the expected output is 2.  Why?  If position matters, it should be 1.  If position doesn't matter, it should be 3.  No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends, do you want to have a mapping between between values and counts, or is the value one of the inputs?

Either way you can probably do it by piping cat, cut, grep, wc -l

Comment: No need for mapping between them, it's purely just the count between the two

Comment: What happens if value A always twice in file 1 and value B appears four times in file 1? You just want the count of the value that appears most often in both files?

Comment: Well they only appear once per file, that is a given. I ended up using `cut -f 2 strain1.vcf strain2.vcf | grep -c -wFf strain1.vcf strain2.vcf`